# MySQL query for counting unread messages

Tags: mysql

I spend two days to make this query to work, but finally... It's not working properly. So I have message system for my users, and for this system, I have two tables. MESSAGES and MESSAGES_BODY.
Table **MESSAGES** contains the following columns:

```
ID | message_body_last | user_from | user_to | user_seen_status
```

column explanation:

- MESSAGE_BODY_LAST-> the last message that the users send to the
  other
- USER_TO -> the message is send to user...
- USER_FROM -> the message is send from...
- USER_SEEN_STATUS-> if is seen from user_to, I put value 1, default is 0. every time when somebody send a message
  to the other, I am changing the value of user_from and user_to every
  time, when somebody send to the other user a message, and column
  user_seen_status is a combination with user_to column, to check if
  the user is seen the message. This table is the header for messages.

Table messages_body is the table where I put all conversations between the users.

The table **MESSAGES_BODY** is with the following columns:

```
ID | MESSAGE_ID | MESSAGE_BODY | USER_FROM | USER_TO | USER_FROM_DELETE | USER_TO_DELETE
```

Column explanations:

- ID - AI field.
- MESSAGE_ID is foreign_key to the MESSAGES.ID
- MESSAGE_BODY - text of the message
- USER_TO - who send the message USER_FROM - from who is the message
- USER_FROM_DELETE - if somebody delete some message, or all messages, I put the ID of the user here.
- USER_TO_DELETE - this is the same field.

So, the problem is that: I want to count how many messages are new. New message is that, If I am user with ID 56 for example ( this is my test ID ),
I have to check. Is messages.user_to is 56 and user_seen_status is 0, BUT I have to check and one more situations. In the table MESSAGES_BODY the column USER_FROM_DELETE and USER_TO_DELETE to NOT contain my ID ( 56 ). because If I delete the messages, counting of new messages from the other users make no sense.

And this is my query:

```
SELECT messages.id, (SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM messages 
WHERE user_to = 56
AND user_seen_status = 0 ) as count_new_messages 
FROM messages
LEFT JOIN messages_body
ON messages_body.message_id = messages.id 
WHERE messages.user_to = 56
AND   messages.user_seen_status = 0
AND  ( messages_body.user_from_delete <> 56
AND   messages_body.user_to_delete <> 56)
```

The query is working, BUT if I have only one conversation... ( in table MESSAGES, I have only one row, each conversation between the users is one row in MESSAGES table, and many rows in MESSAGES_BODY)
If I have more that one conversations the COUNT(*) function is returning me TWO rows with equal data and doesn't matter if the second conversation is with deleted status, he shows me two new messages.

How to get the real number only of new messages ?

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer below, and remove the `[SOLVED]` from the title. Posting an answer then marking it as accepted is the best way to indicate to the community your issue has been corrected.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the advice.

Answer (score -2):

[**SOLVED**]

After 5 min. more, I get my error. I was counting the rows from MESSAGES table, NOT from MESSAGES_BODY.
This is my working query, without sub query.

```
SELECT messages.id, COUNT(messages_body.id) as count_value
                                FROM messages
              LEFT JOIN messages_body
                  ON messages_body.message_id = messages.id 

              WHERE messages.user_to = 56
                AND   messages.user_seen_status = 0
                AND   messages_body.user_from_delete <> 56
                AND   messages_body.user_to_delete <> 56
```

Now is working exactly how I want.

Comment: In the absence of a GROUP BY clause, this answer doesn't make a whole lot of sense.

Comment: I was try it with GROUP BY but the results was not that I was searching for. Thanks for -1 ...

Comment: You're welcome; the downvote reflects the fact that this answer is not useful (either to yourself or others).

Comment: It's useful for me and it's working. If you have better solutions, please..

Comment: There is no problem in SQL for which this is a valid solution.